# Spring excluded some static html files not processed by thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

[image]In my springboot WebApplication,I had created one folder called `templates` which holds all the dynamic content html files and it will use thymeleaf to render the html content .

Here my question is I  want only  this folder `templates` parsed with thyemeleaf. But for other html files in any folders I just want to return the static html file. Anyone know how?

Can we use below code to define the resourceHandlers?

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
```

thanks very much for your answers ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @benkuly's answer I look at the springboot code carefully and found the issue is that springboot had autconfigured these paths as static resources [ResourceProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ResourceProperties.java):

```
private static final String[] SERVLET_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { "/" };

private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```

So above two paths will be used for static resource's location .
Here I want to parse the services.html and aboutus.html which is located in our root classpath, so exception these default static resource locations ,we still need to add this static path: `"classpath:/"`

Hope this question could help some others understand the static resources in springboot clearly .thank.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot maps all files in `/srs/main/resources/static` to your root-location.

Comment: ,yes I know that default static mapping using in springboot ,but i want my folder structure like the attached screenshot . Only the `templates` folder's html files we used thymeleaf to parse the content .for other folder I don't want it to parse as thyemeleaf tempalte . any suggestion ?

Comment: Files in static folder are static and not processed by thymeleaf.

Comment: yes, how can I parse the above screenshot's `service.html` and `aboutus.html` as static resource using the resourceHandler here? I only want the `templates` folder to be parse as thymeleaf ? thanks .

Comment: I don't understand. By default Thymeleaf only parse files in the `templates` folder.

Comment: yes,@benkuly. I found the problem is because  that springboot auto configured only some static paths as static resource .see the below's answer i had found . Really thanks for your comments.